# Duda relación OneToOne JPA con clave primaria compuesta

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo definida la siguiente relación bidireccional OneToOne con clave primaria compuesta que no funciona:

```
   @Embeddable
    public class SolicitudGUCDetalleId implements Serializable {

      @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
      @Size(max = 36)
      private String idPedido;

      @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
      private long idLinea;

      ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
    public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

      @EmbeddedId
      private SolicitudGUCDetalleId id;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
      private SolicitudGUCEnvio solicitudGUCEnvio;

      ...
    }

    @Embeddable
    public class SolicitudGUCEnvioId implements Serializable {

      @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
      @Size(max = 36)
      private String idPedido;

      @Column(name = "IDLINEA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
      private long idLinea;

      ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
    public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {


      @EmbeddedId
      private SolicitudGUCEnvioId id;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
          @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA"),
          @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO")})
      private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

      ...
    }
```

Buscando información sobre el problema, he encontrado dos formas diferentes de implementar dicha relación que si que funcionan:

1 - Utilizar la misma clase para definir la clave primaria compuesta:

```
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
  private SolicitudGUCEnvio solicitudGUCEnvio;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA"),
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO")})
  private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

  ...
}
```

2 - Convertir la relación en un ManyToOne que tendrá un SET con un único elemento:

```
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCDetalleId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCDetalleId id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
  private Set<SolicitudGUCEnvio> solicitudes;

  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCEnvioId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCEnvioId id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA",
          nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO",
          nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)})
  private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

  ...
}
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible definir la relación tal y como lo estaba intentando en el primer ejemplo y si no es posible, saber por qué razón.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución que estaba buscando:

```
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Size(max = 36)
    private String idPedido;

    @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long idLinea;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SolicitudGUCId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
    private SolicitudGUCEnvio solicitudGUCEnvio;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SolicitudGUCId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO")})
    @MapsId
    private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

    ...
}
```

En las especificaciones de JPA se indica que se debe de usar la anotación `@MapsId` junto con `@JoinColumns` para este caso. Yo estaba utilizando `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns`.

[JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) - Pagina 38. ("Note that the use of PrimaryKeyJoinColumn instead of MapsId would result in the same mapping in this example. Use of MapsId
is preferred for the mapping of derived identities.")